# C3 JS Chart - Grouping

Tags: angular, d3.js, c3.js

I have the following dataset that needs to be rendered as charts:

```
let jsonData = [
  { col: 'c1', row: 'r1', formula1: '100' },
  { col: 'c1', row: 'r2', formula2: '200' },
  { col: 'c2', row: 'r1', formula1: '300' },
  { col: 'c2', row: 'r2', formula2: '400' }
]
```

I am using C3 + Angular 2 to render the UI.

I have converted the data to the following format:

```
let column = [
  ['x', 'c1', 'c2'],
  ['r1_formula1', 100, 300],
  ['r2_formula2', 200, 400]
]
```

My requirement consists in grouping the above data set as per different `formula` attribute - like  **formula1** & **formula2**.

Currently grouping happens like: `r1_formula1` & `r2_formula2`

Is there any way to achieve this in C3.js?

Comment: So you just want to change the names of grouping(r1_formula to formula1) or something else ?

Comment: I can have combinations like r1_formula2, r2_formula1.... Intention is not only to change the grouping label. When i select formula1 it should show/hide all formula1 combinations.